# Magento 2.2 - How to remove product Meta Keywords maxlength validation from backend?

Tags: magento2, database, admin, validation, meta-keywords

I want to remove validation for product `meta_keyword` from backend or else to increase the length of the product `meta_keyword`.

I also tried to remove `maxlength` validation from `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html` file.

I check in the database for `meta_keyword` and DB allow to add more value for it but Magento 2 prevent it to add only 255 length in product `meta_keyword`.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: You can use modifiers for this. Please check link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar Please see updated questions.

Comment: Yes I got it your question. From modifiers it can be achieved. Just follow the url which I shared.

Comment: Take a look at this question from today, that should be the solution for you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269820/magento-2-how-to-remove-character-limit-from-meta-keyword-field-in-product